# ffmpeg HLS playlist not starting at the beginning

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, hls

I'm attempting to take a 5-minute video file and produce a *single-file* HTTP Live Stream playlist and `.ts` file. The playlist file format can support byte-ranges instead of separate files as of iOS 5, which is a fine target for my use cases. But, when I run my `ffmpeg` command, the first entry in the resulting `.m3u8` playlist does not start at (or even near) byte 0.

For example:

```
ffmpeg -i input -hls_flags single_file out.m3u8
```

Produces a playlist like so:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:63
#EXTINF:1.376367,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:568324@63107840
out.ts
#EXTINF:1.334667,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:235564@63676164
out.ts
#EXTINF:1.918589,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:343288@63911728
out.ts
#EXTINF:10.427078,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:3311996@64255016
out.ts
#EXTINF:5.672333,
#EXT-X-BYTERANGE:52828@67567012
out.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Note that the first `EXT-X-BYTERANGE` entry is not `@0` -- it's about 63 MB into the 68 MB `.ts` file. Indeed, when loading the playlist into a `<video>` tag and opening the HTML with Safari, video playback starts about 20 seconds from the end of the input video, not at 0, and there's no way to scrub any earlier.

Why has `ffmpeg` produced a playlist that *doesn't include all of the video*? When I watch the `.ts` file produced alongside the playlist, all the video content is present.

I see this on recent [`ffmpeg` static builds](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) under Linux, as well as a Homebrew-built version of `ffmpeg` 2.7.1 under OS X.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After reading [the HLS documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-1) *again*, I finally noticed this option:

> **`hls_list_size` *`size`***
>
> Set the maximum number of playlist entries. If set to 0 the list file will contain all the segments. Default value is 5.

Sure enough, in my initial question, there are 5 `EXT-X-BYTERANGE` entries from the end of the video, consistent with the stated default value. Setting `hls_list_size` to `0` as indicated does in fact ensure the video starts at the beginning and includes all the expected byte ranges.

Comment: What a bizarre default! When using byte ranges, you'd think they would realise that you want a playlist for the entire file (by default).

Comment: In hindsight, I think ffmpeg's default was selected with the (probably correct) thinking that the most common use case of the feature would be to encode real-time streams, where only the last few segments are what the visitor might want as they start playing.